# Bug in formatting? Lists and Code

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, markdown, code-formatting

On this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39880680/trouble-with-2-functions-in-c), I tried to format code, (indented 4 spaces) followed by a Unordered List to document the params, then another line of code, and more documentation.

The second line of code will not appear as code.  I've tried a variety of BR and P and other separators, but it doesn't work.

What am I seeing? Is it browser specific? is it already known? Am I doing something wrong?

---

```
Student* findhighest(Student*class, int length, Type search);
```

- class - the array of Student Stuctures
- length - how many students are there
- type - the enum telling the functions which part of the structure to access
- return: The function returns the student with the highest average specified by the enum.

  void getaverages(Student* class, int length, Type Search);
  // This does not appear as code.
- class- the array of Student structures
- length- how many students there are
- type - the enum telling the functions which part of the structure to access.